# I don't want the sed output to be displayed while running the program

Tags: shell-script

```
cd /path/
sed 's/.ear//g' file | tee file1
```

The code saves the correct data in file1, but also displays the output while running the script. I just want to save the output in file1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, after you verified that the sed command works (by inspecting its output), you could do `sed -i xxxx` (no tee anymore) to write to the file directly. Or, if you just want to create a new file, use redirect instead of tee...

```
sed xxxx my_file > my_new_file
```